# Angularjs : Display accolades {{ }} several milliseconds before rendering

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, render

I am going to create an application with Angularjs. I have several modals (with the ng-dialog libraries) to create, modify data like an user for example.
When I open it, I can always see during several milliseconds names variables  with accolades like {{user.name}}, before it renders the real value.

It is not really beautiful and then if someone has an idea about how to manage this type of display problems, please share it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to deal with it, you could either use [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) or [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directives

Answer (score 0):

Check angular ngCloak directive documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind).  Here is the official documentation on it:

> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a template is momentarily displayed >by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, >it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading

Usage:

```
Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
```